# docusignapi salesforce connector stopped functioning

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I've been using the salesforce connector for a couple years. I have a custom object set up in the connector. It is to create a task in salesforce on the opportunity record that the docusign envelope is related to. The task has information from secure custom fields in the document.

Everything has been working fine until recently. Now the task is still being created successfully, and the data from the envelope is all there, but several of the fields that used to pass data to fields on the newly created task are not passing the data. No error message, just no attempt to pass certain fields. Other fields are passing data without a problem. I have noticed that the fields that are NOT passing data are all fields with an encrypted text data type in salesforce.

My understanding is that salesforce recently upgraded their security to require a certain type of security (that's a little over my head, though) and I'm wondering if that could be related? Is there anyone that might know why certain fields that are set to pass data in the connector would stopped passing the data?

Any help that anyone could give would be greatly appreciated. (Salesforce enterprise edition)...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

We just had this issue.  We noticed that in our custom settings and sites it had our server NA2 list as the endpoint.  We changed it to the default docusign endpoint and it worked.  Not sure if you have the same issue but it is worth a try.